# Как правильно составить SQL, чтобы не было совпадений?

Tags: mysql

Нужно вывести строки из таблицы `Artist` с условием, что в таблице `Genresartist` в ячейке `artist` есть `id` из таблицы `Artist`, но в то же время в таблице `Genresplus` среди записей в ячейке `artist` не было `id` из таблицы `Artist`.

Вот запрос:

```
SELECT `a`.* FROM `Artist` AS `a` INNER JOIN `Genresartist` AS `g` ON g.artist = a.id INNER JOIN `Genresplus` AS `gp` ON gp.artist != a.id WHERE (g.uid = 10) LIMIT 10
```

Comment: какой бы не был запрос. для исключения совпадений есть distinct...

Comment: и group by

Comment: и он тоже :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Artist.ID
FROM Artist 
INNER JOIN Genresartist ON Genresartist.Artist = Artist.ID
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS
      (
          SELECT NULL
          FROM Genresplus 
          WHERE
              Genresplus.Artist = Artist.ID

       )
GROUP BY Artist.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
SELECT `a`.* 
FROM `Artist` AS `a`, `Genresartist` AS `g`
where g.artist = a.id 
and a.id not in 
    (select id from `Genresplus`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вашего вопроса более логичным ( и быстрым ) будет такой запрос:

```
select *
from Artist a
where
  exists (
    select 1
    from Genresartist g
    where
      g.Artist = a.ID
  ) and
  not exists (
    select 1
    from Genresplus g
    where
      g.Artist = a.ID
  )
```